# How to set TCP/IP abort interval or timeout in Windows XP?

Tags: firefox, timeout, tcp

Does anyone know how to set the TCP/IP abort interval or timeout in Windows XP?

In my machine, when I open `http://129.129.129.129` in IE, Firefox, or Google Chrome,
it will cost about 20 seconds to abort, it's too long to wait, I want to adjust the TCP/IP abort interval to 10 seconds.

I've tried the `TcpMaxDataRetransmissions`, `TcpMaxConnectRetransmissions` in `regedit`, it does not work.

Comment: Finnaly, i found that setting TcpMaxConnectRetransmissions=1 makes the timeout became to 10 senconds, i don't understand why.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at [TCP Retransmission Behavior](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms819737.aspx) article on the MSDN site:

A number of registry values under the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSetServices\Tcpip\Parameters` registry key adjust the behavior of TCP retransmission:

> The per-adapter value **TcpInitialRtt** controls the retransmission
>   timer. This timer identifies the number of milliseconds to wait for an
>   acknowledgment after the first transmission of a segment before
>   retransmitting it.
>
> The **TcpMaxConnectRetransmissions** value indicates the maximum
>   number of retransmissions that can be sent for a new connection
>   request.
>
> The **TcpMaxDataRetransmissions** value indicates the maximum number
>   of retransmissions that can be sent on an existing connection. The
>   default is 5.
>
> The retransmission time-out is adjusted on the fly to match the characteristics of the connection, using Smoothed Round Trip Time (SRTT) calculations… The retransmission time-out for a given segment **is doubled** after each retransmission of that segment.

According to [this document](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc739819%28WS.10%29.aspx) the default value of **TcpInitialRtt** is **3** and **TcpMaxConnectRetransmissions** is **2**.
So the default connection timeout is calculated like this: `3 + 3*2 + 3*2*2 = 21 seconds`,
after you set *TcpMaxConnectRetransmissions* to 1 it becames: `3 + 3*2 = 9 seconds`.